# Open Winforms screen after every one minute if the form is closed

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

A form should open only when there is an event if there is no event it should not display on the screen. So Basically i thought of using a timer to do this. An exe will continously be running and after every minute it checks the db to see if there is data and if there is it shows up on the screen and will only be closed manually with user interaction. After a minute it checks again and displays the form if Data is present in the DB.

I used system.threading.Timer in Program.cs file to open a  window after every minute.Below is the code

```
timer = new System.Threading.Timer((s) => { 
  EL.CustomMessageBox l = new EL.CustomMessageBox(); 
  l.ShowDialog();                
}, null, TimeSpan.Zero, 60000);
```

After certain time I see that this exe is still running in the taskmanager but even though there is data in the DB it stops showing up on the screen. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Put a console log message before you create the new dialog object to see if the timer is still firing - that will at least tell you if the issue is dialog related or if the timer is dying.

Comment: You cannot create, access, nor update any UI element on a non-UI thread.

Comment: In addition to running only on a UI thread, consider minimizing and restoring the form, rather than having a modal dialog box pop up and disappear.

Comment: @Enigmativity: That's vacuously true.  Any thread where you create a UI element *is* a UI thread.

Comment: You need a message pump. It's not as simple as creating a thread.

Answer (score 3):

`System.Threading.Timer` runs its callback on a threadpool thread.  You should never use a threadpool thread for UI work, because:

1. They don't run a message dispatch loop.
2. You don't control when the thread gets recycled.  UI windows have thread affinity and if their thread exits all the associated windows go poof immediately (you won't even get `WM_DESTROY` messages).

A normal `Application.Run` loop on the main thread, with a hidden main window and a UI timer will serve you much better.

Comment: Hello Ben Thanks for the Response. I followed this approach and looks like it is working.

Answer (score 2):

I would pass my own custom [ApplicationContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.applicationcontext?view=netcore-3.1) to `Application.Run()` in `program.cs`.

This will allow you to have NO INTERFACE until your conditions are met.  The application will also continue to run (even when you close the Forms) until you explicitly call [Application.Exit()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.exit?view=netcore-3.1).

You can keep a reference to your Form at class level.  This will help you decide if you need to work with the existing one, or create a new one.

Note that I'm using the [System.Windows.Forms.Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer?view=netcore-3.1), not the threaded timer.

Something like...

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new MyContext());
    }
}

public class MyContext : ApplicationContext
{

    private EL.CustomMessageBox l = null;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer;

    public MyContext()
    {
        timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        timer.Interval = (int)TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1).TotalMilliseconds;
        timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
        timer.Start();
    }

    private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool result = true; // hit the database and get an answer
        if (result)
        {
            if (l == null || l.IsDisposed)
            {
                // no form has been created yet, or the previous one was closed
                // create a new instance
                l = new EL.CustomMessageBox();
                l.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                // if we get in here, then the previous form is still being displayed
                // if your form can be minimized, you might need to restore it
                // if (l.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
                // {
                //     restore the window in here?
                // }
            }

            // update the form "l" with some data?
            l.xxx = yyy;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't help but think that the other answers, massively technically correct as they are, don't actually solve the problem because they probably don't make sense if you aren't aware of how Windows works. Idle_Mind's is closest to what I'd do, though if the forms designer is familiar I'd go for a solution that basically just uses that - as such I present what I would do to solve the task you're faced with:

- Have an app with one form (or make this form an autonomous one within another app, but for now maybe do it as a dedicated app for simplicity) - make a new Windows Forms project
- Have a Timer (a Windows Forms timer, out of the toolbox, not a System.Threading timer) with an interval of 60000 and Enabled = true
- Have a timer Tick event handler on your form (double click the timer in the tray under the form designer to attach an event handler) that queries the DB and finds if there are any messages
- If there are new messages, adds them to a listbox or something, and calls `this.Show()` to show the form
- Have an eventhandler attached to the FormClosing event so when the user clicks X, the form hides instead of closes:

```
private void MyForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing) 
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        Hide();
    }
}
```

- Maybe have the FormClosing event clear the messages listbox. This way if the form opens and the user is on lunch, the messages will build up and build up, then they can read them and clear them by closing the form. Calling Show on an already-visible form does nothing, so the messages will just accumulate into the listbox if more messages come in and the form is already visible

---

Good quick rule of thumb; never use System.Threading Timer in a Windows Forms app. Use a timer out of the forms designer toolbox instead. Only use a threading timer if you're writing a service or Console app etc. For stability reasons, Windows controls absolutely must be accessed by the thread that originally created the control. Windows forms timer is aware of this and its Tick event can safely access the controls (a form is a control, showing it requires to access it) in a Forms app

Comment: Thank you for the Detailed Explanation. it helps. I have implemented it and currently testing it and it looks great. Will run it overthe weekend and see if it keeps going.

Comment: The only thing I'd suggest to that effect, is to make sure the DB call can't fail with an unhandled exception - at some point some spurious timeout or something will happen and e.g. connection.Open() will throw an error, so if you're wanting to make sure the app keeps running, make sure that this in particular is handled. Also if the messages being shown are big, have something that limits how many there can be total (like removing all messages older than X days) so you don't end up with an app that just constantly eats memory as it adds thousands of messages to a listbox

Comment: Thank you sure will keep that in Mind.

Answer (score -1):

You should call `Invoke` to execute your delegate on the thread that owns the control's underlying window handle.

Something like this should work:

```
timer = new System.Threading.Timer((s) => { 
  EL.CustomMessageBox l = new EL.CustomMessageBox(); 
  l.Invoke((Action) () => 
  {
    l.ShowDialog();
  });               
}, null, TimeSpan.Zero, 60000);
```

Or even better, use this extension method:

```
public static void InvokeIfRequired(this Control c, MethodInvoker action)
{
    if (c.InvokeRequired)
    {
        c.Invoke(action);
    }
    else
    {
        action();
    }
}
```

And call it like this:

```
l.InvokeIfRequired(() => { l.ShowDialog(); });
```

Further information can be found at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-make-thread-safe-calls-to-windows-forms-controls?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Comment: He just created the window, so "the thread that owns the control's underlying window handle" is the current thread, and calling `Invoke` will make no difference.

Comment: Where does he say "I just created the thread", maybe it is a winforms application and has a message loop. The OP did not share enough code sample to deduce that. He didn't say his project type or which synchronization context he's in.

Comment: Not "just created the thread".  He just **created the window**.  `new EL.CustomMessageBox` happened one line before.

Comment: If we are in a WinForms application and in a single threaded apartment. We can create as many windows as runtime allows us. So we can't know if he just created his first window or he just opens another form with calling `ShowDialog`. We shouldn't make assumptions without seeing the full code.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it is the first or not.  It matters which thread owns the object `l` that you are calling `Invoke()` on.  That's clearly the current thread, because the construction of `l` is right there in the code we were given.